# C# for, foreach and foreach with SIMD performance

Tags: c#

I playing with SIMD in C# and the first example which I try to optimize is summing elements of an array.

In my code, I have array `long[] data`, that contains `1e8` elements:

```
public class SumLoopBenchmark
{
    private readonly long[] data;

    public SumLoopBenchmark()
    {
        data = new Random(0).GenerateLongSequence((int)1e8);
    }
}
```

So I test three implementation of the algorithm:

Simple foreach:

```
long sum = 0;
foreach (var element in data)
    sum += element;
return sum;
```

Simple for loop:

```
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    sum += data[i];
return sum;
```

For with SIMD:

```
var sums = Vector<long>.Zero;
var vectorSize = Vector<long>.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += vectorSize)
    sums += new Vector<long>(data, i);
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
    sum += sums[i];
return sum;
```

I measure run-time for this functions with `BenchmarkDotNet` and get next results:

- Simple foreach: 70.7 ms
- Simple for loop: 79.4 ms
- SIMD for loop: 59.1 ms

Now I have two questions:

1. Why foreach outperform simple for loop?
2. Why SIMD for loop only 14% faster than foreach loop? I expected x2 speed up at least.

For the first question I have an assumption based on CIL generated by the compiler: for loop contain operation of access to `data` field in the loop, while foreach copy it to local variable.

For the second question I can only assume, that sum operation is pretty fast, so pipeline, branch predictor, and instruction cache works fine and with SIMD we lost some of these properties and because of this speed up not so impressive.

Can you explain me situation?

Comment: The for(;;) loop is slower because the jitter is conservative and assumes that the array might be reassigned.  Even though it is readonly.  So it reloads the array pointer and checks the index in the loop.  Move the code into a separate method and pass the array through an argument, now it is just as fast as foreach.  The `Vector<T>`, hmya, there is a reason they did not add it to the framework.  It should be 4 times as fast.  But having no alignment guarantee on the array and overzealous bounds checking bogs it down.  It can be that fast, but you have to use `long*` instead of `long[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Does `long*` helps in this case? I try to write `unsafe` code, that manually tries to align the first element of array, but it has no effect(
Maybe because of CLR alignment constraints we can't get very fast SIMD code, or it wrong argument?

Comment: You may already know this, but it's much easier to get the extra performance you're expecting by linking to a native c++ dll if you can.